# Unable to pass parameter to the Controller in Visual Studio (2019 v)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes

I am currently unable to pass the parameter from a method I created to the Controller. When I run it manually with the parameter in postman, everything works OK.

How do I pass the parameter to the Controller? Is there any way to set this up to automatically route instead of creating individuals routes based on different parameters? It's a very basic application.

Error Message:
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44364/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'WebInterface' that matches the request."}

CONTROLLER:

```
using WebInterfaceAPI.Helpers;
using WebInterfaceAPI.Services;
using WebInterfaceAPI.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace WebInterfaceAPI.Controllers
{
    public class WebInterfaceController : ApiController
    {
        private NurseService NurseService { get; set; }

        public WebInterfaceController()
        {
            NurseService = new NurseService();
        }

        #region Nurse Actions
        /// <summary>
        /// Removes specified nurse
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nurseID"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult RemoveNurse(int nurseID)
        {
            APIResponseModel result = NurseService.removeNurse(nurseID);
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                return Ok(result.Message);

            }
            else
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result.Message);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
};
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

METHOD: (NurseService.cs)

```
public APIResponseModel removeNurse(int nurseID)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new DataBase())
            {
                OnCallNurses_Nurses rowToDelete = (from nurse in dbContext.OnCallNurses_Nurses
                                                   where nurse.id == nurseID
                                                   select nurse).SingleOrDefault();

                if (rowToDelete == null)
                {
                    return new APIResponseModel(false, "Cannot delete nurse.");
                }
                else
                {
                    dbContext.OnCallNurses_Nurses.Remove(rowToDelete);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return new APIResponseModel(true, "Nurse successfully removed.");
                }
            }
        }
```

FRONT-END

```
function removeNurse(nID) {

$('#loader').removeClass('d-none');
var webMethod = "https://localhost:44364/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse";
// var webMethod = "https://webinterface.com/api/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        nurseID: nID
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        // $(nurseRow).remove();
        $('#loader').addClass('d-none');

    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code as well.pls?

Comment: Hi, @Sergey I updated the Controller section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the url and remove contentType and type from ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "https://localhost:44364/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse",
        data: {
            nurseID: nID
        },
......
});
```

and change the action header:

```
[Route("~/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse")]
 public IHttpActionResult RemoveNurse(int nurseID)
```

or change your controller header

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class WebInterfaceController : ApiController
```

and add attribute routing to config:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

but the better way will be to  pass id using routing

```
$.ajax({
        url:  "https://localhost:44364/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse/"+nID,
        success: function (data) 
......
});
```

in this case the action will be

```
[Route("~/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse/{nurseId}")]
 public IHttpActionResult RemoveNurse(int nurseID)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I am still getting the same error message. I updated the Controller code because it should be nurseID, not id.

Comment: It was my mistake. My parameter in the Controller was id, not nurseID. I figured you thought that was the mistake.

Comment: unfortunately, I am still getting the same error even after adding in the attribute to RouteConfig.cs . Thanks for trying.

Comment: @AlexGreenwood  I just noticed that you have a wrong ajax url too. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I return an error 405. The localhost needs to be there since I am running the program locally for development reasons. I cannot figure this out, and it's been a few hours. Very frustrated ! However, thank you for trying.

Comment: Did you try to put id in the route?

Comment: Yes. [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/api/WebInterface/RemoveNurse/{nurseID:int}")]
        public IHttpActionResult RemoveNurse(int nurseID)
        {

Comment: You have to remove  [HttpPost]  from your action. You don't need it at all.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted by this. It works excellent in Postman when I do it, but the Controller just doesn't see the parameter. it's wild.

Comment: Again ,  remove [HttpPost] . It is not in my code.

Comment: Apologies, I did not see your update, but it works. I am grateful for you today.

Comment: It was my pleasure to help.